# How to control spacing in toc for different sections?

Tags: spacing, table-of-contents

I need to have a TOC that has double space between Chapter titles but single space between sections and subsections. I know there are several related questions on this matter, but the difference is that when using some of the suggested solutions like `\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{-2pt}`  or `\renewcommand\cftchapafterpnum{\vspace{}}` that changes the spacing before or after the section or subsection, and if the title in question is one-line long is fine, but if its a long three lines title of a section then, it gives very irregular spacing, with the desired space above the section title, and then what looks like one half spacing and again single spaced after the page number.
Another solution I have tried is within the actual text use something like `\section[\singlespacing{\noindent Long title}]{Long title}`but then although I get single spaced lines in the TOC, I also get some undesired vertical space between the section number and the beginning of the section title.  Is there any way of uniformly changing the spacing in the TOC by hierarchical sections, or avoid the extra vertical space in my second approach?  Also, it is worth mentioning that I am loading the `setspace`package and using `\onehalfspacing` on the preamble of my document, since the main body of it should be one-half spaced. Thanks a lot,
Here is how it looks what I have:

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{report}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\setlength{\cftbeforesecskip}{-2.5pt}
\setlength{\cftbeforesubsecskip}{-2.5pt}
\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\chapter{this is a really really long title that someone else wrote for all the penguins in the world}
\section{this is a really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really long title having more than three lines of text to appear on the toc.}
\subsection{this is a really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really long title having more than three lines of text to appear on the toc.}
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

On this MWE I show one of the options I tried.  I hope someone can comment on this.  Thanks.

Comment: You are aware that the ToC entries are not intended to be really long? That's why the `\section[short title]{long title}` - way was introduced/designed

Comment: Not really.  The problem anyway is that my university requires the whole title of the section to appear on the TOC for my written dissertation.  Thanks for the comment, anyway.

Comment: Well, in this case, you should show us an example of your file in order to get some clue -- without a document, it's just guessing around

Comment: Thanks.  I posted an edited version, trying to summarize the parts of the document that are involved.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Go for it ;-)

Comment: @jealopez I extended the MWE to work, but reading the question , i really don't know where which spacing shall be? You are talking about double- and singlespacing, but there is non in your example.

Comment: @Johannes_B you are right, in my example I did not included a long title, and the way I wrote it is how it appears on the main document, which includes each chapter with `\include{Chapter name}`  and is inside those included chapters where there are some `\section{Very long section name}` that are appearing one half spaced on the TOC and that I don't know how to make them be single spaced.  Thanks.  @ChristianHupfer

Comment: @ChristianHupfer thank you for your help so far.  I added extra lines to my MWE for section and subsection to try to clarify where my issue is coming from.  Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: In the TOC (after removing the settings to `\cftbeforesecskip` and `\cftbeforesubsecskip`), I see a wide space between the entry for subsubsection 1.1.1 and the following chapter entry, with no extra space between section titles. It's not really clear what you want to achieve.

Comment: @egreg what I need is the spacing within the section and subsection titles in the toc to be single spaced, all together.  That is double-space \chapter{title} double-space, start single spacing \section{long title} \subsection{long title} \section{another long title and several other sections and subsections} end-single-space, double-space \chapter{another chapter title} etc... hope I was able to express clearly this time.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hook into `\cftchapafterpnum` for adding some vertical space after a chapter title in the table of contents.

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{report}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\renewcommand{\cftchapafterpnum}{\vspace{\cftbeforechapskip}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\chapter{this is a really really long title that someone else wrote for all the penguins in the world}
\section{this is a really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really long title having more than three lines of text to appear on the toc.}
\subsection{this is a really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really really long title having more than three lines of text to appear on the toc.}
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, long titles have nothing to do with the problem; you seem to be loading `setspace` with `\onehalfspacing`, probably to comply with silly requirements by your institution (if not, just use standard spacing, you'll leave happier).

Just issue `\singlespacing` when doing the table of contents.

```
\documentclass[12pt,reqno]{report}
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\renewcommand{\cftchapafterpnum}{\vspace{\cftbeforechapskip}}

\onehalfspacing

\begin{document}

\begingroup\singlespacing
\tableofcontents
\endgroup

\chapter{this is a really really long title that someone else wrote 
for all the penguins in the world}
\section{this is a really really really really really really really
really really long title having more than three lines of text to appear on the toc.}
\subsection{this is a really really really really really really really
really really really long title having more than three lines of text to appear on the toc.}

\blinddocument

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I have done that, and that adds the space after the chapter title, it works well just as you showed it here.  What I cannot achieve is to get the sections, subsections altogether to be single-spaced, they look more like one half spaced, and I am being requested to make sure they are single spaced.  I have used `\cftbeforesecskip` but that won't change the spacing within all the sections sub-sections but only for the lines before each of them. From your example, what I need is to have all the spacing from 1.1 to the end of 1.1.1 to be reduced to "look" single spaced. Hope I explained myself.

Comment: @jealopez Sorry, but I can't see any “one half spaced” part in the picture. Are you perhaps loading the `setspace` package and using `\onehalfspace` or similar things?

Comment: Yes, you are right!! that might be the problem, the thing is that all the document (actual chapters, sections and subsections) should be one-half space, and I am indeed loading `setspace` and using `\onehalfspace`, is there a way of keeping that and still getting on the TOC the single space in section and subsection titles?  Thanks.

Comment: @jealopez Just set `\singlespacing` for the TOC, a version with it is online.