# Level Specific Spacing in Table of Contents

Tags: table-of-contents, vertical-alignment, tocloft, thesis, etoc

I am trying to control the vertical spacing between entries in the table of contents.  Specifically, I need Double space between major section headings and whenever changing levels and single space between like-level sub headings.

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft} % add nested figures
\usepackage{subfigure}


\renewcommand{\cftchapdotsep}{\cftdotsep}       % Give chapters dots too
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont}                    % Change to normal font 
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{}               % Change to normal font 

% Center the word 'CONTENTS' over table of contents
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\hspace*{\fill}\normalfont\normalsize CONTENTS \hspace*{\fill}}  

%add page flush right at top of TOC
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{%
    \\[\baselineskip]\mbox{}\hfill{\normalfont Page}}


% My attempt to contol the spacing using tocloft
\renewcommand{\cftchapafterpnum}{\vspace{\cftbeforechapskip}}
%\renewcommand{\cftsecafterpnum}{\vspace{\cftbeforechapskip}}


\begin{document}



\tableofcontents

\chapter{First Chapter}
\chapter{Second Chapter}

\section{First Section}
\section{Second Section}
\subsection{First Subsection}
\subsection{Second Subsection}
\subsubsection{First Subsubsection}
\subsubsection{Second subsubsection}
\chapter{Third Chapter}


\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image]

I need there to be:

- Double Spacing between Section 2.2 and Section 2.2.1

This [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/241445/how-to-control-spacing-in-toc-for-different-sections) seems similar, but I cant understand what the command `\renewcommand{\cftchapafterpnum}{\vspace{\cftbeforechapskip}}` does.  A simple trial an error allows me to conclude that the line

```
\renewcommand{\cftchapafterpnum}{\vspace{\cftbeforechapskip}}
```

creates an extra space between the Chapter 1 and Section 1.1, but i dont understand why

```
\renewcommand{\cftsecafterpnum}{\vspace{\cftbeforesecskip}}
```

does not change the resulting document.  I have reviewed the documentation for [tocloft](http://www.ctex.org/documents/packages/contents/tocloft.pdf), but I cant seem to understand why you chaniging `\cftchapafterpnum` to `\cftsecafterpnum` has no effect. I hope I am close.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why did you delete your answer?

Comment: @TorbjørnT. because the solution also added a space between sec 2.1 and sec 2.2.  I only needed double spacing when section level change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easily done with [etoc](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/etoc) in "Another Compatibility Mode" (see its docs).

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{book}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[subfigure]{tocloft} % add nested figures
\usepackage{subfigure}


\renewcommand{\cftchapdotsep}{\cftdotsep}       % Give chapters dots too
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\normalfont}                    % Change to normal font 
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{}               % Change to normal font 

% Center the word 'CONTENTS' over table of contents
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{\hspace*{\fill}\normalfont\normalsize CONTENTS \hspace*{\fill}}  

%add page flush right at top of TOC
\renewcommand{\cftaftertoctitle}{%
    \\[\baselineskip]\mbox{}\hfill{\normalfont Page}}


% OP's attempt to control the spacing using tocloft
%\renewcommand{\cftchapafterpnum}{\vspace{\cftbeforechapskip}}
%\renewcommand{\cftsecafterpnum}{\vspace{\cftbeforechapskip}}

\usepackage{etoc}
\newskip\myskip
\myskip\cftbeforechapskip
\cftbeforechapskip0pt\relax

\etocsetstyle{chapter}
  {}
  {\etociffirst{}{\addvspace{\myskip}}}
  {\etocifnumbered
     {\etocsavedchaptertocline{\numberline{\etocnumber}\etocname}{\etocpage}}
     {\etocsavedchaptertocline{\etocname}{\etocpage}}%
  }
  {}

\etocsetstyle{section}
  {\addvspace{\myskip}}%
  {}
  {\etocifnumbered
     {\etocsavedsectiontocline{\numberline{\etocnumber}\etocname}{\etocpage}}
     {\etocsavedsectiontocline{\etocname}{\etocpage}}%
  }
  {\addvspace{\myskip}}

\etocsetstyle{subsection}
  {\addvspace{\myskip}}
  {}
  {\etocifnumbered
     {\etocsavedsubsectiontocline{\numberline{\etocnumber}\etocname}{\etocpage}}
     {\etocsavedsubsectiontocline{\etocname}{\etocpage}}%
  }
  {\addvspace{\myskip}}

\etocsetstyle{subsubsection}
  {\addvspace{\myskip}}
  {}
  {\etocifnumbered
     {\etocsavedsubsubsectiontocline{\numberline{\etocnumber}\etocname}{\etocpage}}
     {\etocsavedsubsubsectiontocline{\etocname}{\etocpage}}%
  }
  {\addvspace{\myskip}}



\begin{document}



\tableofcontents

\chapter{First Chapter}
\section{First Section}
\section{Second Section}
\chapter{Second Chapter}
\section{Third Section}
\section{Fourth Section}
\subsection{First Subsection}
\subsection{Second Subsection}
\subsubsection{First Subsubsection}
\subsubsection{Second subsubsection}
\section{Fifth Section}
\section{Sixth Section}
\chapter{Third Chapter}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The point is that `etoc` is designed to detect when one goes from subsection to section or from section to chapter etc in the TOC.

For maximal compatibility I have doubled all styles into numbered and un-numbered situations, so that secnumdepth counter can be changed and it still works.